# Number roadmaps as A001 instead of A1 using Word page numbers

Tags: ms-office, printing, formatting

To identify roadmaps provided to participants to a biycle randonnee, I want to number them as A001 to A150, B001 to B150 and C001 to C150. 
After printing the required roadmaps in a printshop, I number them at home with my printer, starting with the pile A001 to A150. To do that, I use the page numbering of Word. 
Unfortunately, it prints as A1 to A150, omitting the 0 when at the beginning of a figure. How can I change Word behaviour so that it would print A001 to A150 ?
TIA

Comment: Another place you could ask would be https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac

Comment: Thanks. I have given up, believing this is not feasible. I printed three series: the A001 to A009, the A010 to A099 and the A100 to A150. Same for B and C (total 9 runs). Better than wasting my time with Microsoft.